How does energy work in Inscryption?
In Inscryption, once you defeat Leshy and unlock the new game option, leading to the second part of the game, the gameplay loop changes drastically.
One of the changes is an energy bar that shows up during battles with enemies. Some cards require this energy to be placed on the board. However, I also noticed that energy had gone down to two bars at some point, and I don’t know how. It also replenish somehow, I think.
How does the energy system work?
EDIT: I should clarify that when my energy bar dropped to 2/6, I hadn’t placed any cards that required energy, or done anything with energy at all.

Your maximum energy for each match starts at 1. Every turn, your maximum energy automatically increases by 1 and refills completely. Similar to Hearthstone if you've played that.
So on your second turn, you will have 2 energy. You can play 2 cards that each cost 1, or 1 card that costs 2. You'll see the energy deplete as you use it up.
And then on your third turn, whether you spent energy on turn 2 or not, you will have 3 energy.
A few effects have the ability to add energy. This increases your current and maximum energy. There shouldn't be any effect that lowers your maximum energy.
Edit: As far as I am aware, the only way to lose energy during a turn is by playing cards that cost energy or using activated abilities that cost energy. If you believe that you lost energy without doing either of those things, I would need to see the exact state of the board.

I made an edit to the question, maybe you can help me with it?

Unfortunately, I don’t have a photo. I’ll take your word for it though.
